# How to zoom-in 100% page-width image to keep a fixed height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like an image to span the full-width of the webpage (980px to 2000px+). When I just specify width:100% to the image, then to maintain the aspect ratio the height of the image also becomes pretty big for large sized screens.

```
<img src="imageFileName.jpg" width=100% />
```

To avoid the height issue, I have seen that many websites zoom-in the image, width stays at 100% of the webpage, and they keep the height fixed.

Can anyone please tell me how to zoom in the image so that I can keep the height of the image fixed and also have the image extend to 100% of page width. The zoom part will help with keeping the aspect ratio consistent.

If there is css only solution that will be really great. Thank you. (I could not find the answer by google search so posting a question here)

Answer (score 1):

Create a div element with desired with and height. Then set image as background of that div. Then you can span background as you want.

```
div {
    background: url(img_flwr.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to fix the image 100% height

```
<img src="imageFileName.jpg" width=100% id="image"/>


function img_height()
{
  $("#image").height($(window).height());
}

$(window).scroll(img_height);
$(window).resize(img_height);
```

you may also use `$("#page_width").height()` instead of `$(window).height()`